# Problem with displaying text using drawString

Tags: java, graphics

When I run this program without the "g.drawString ("Play",50,50)" it runs fine. The back ground of the frame is a solid white colour. But when I add that line of code, the back ground of the frame becomes almost transparent. It's like a screen shot of my screen in the 450 by 800 pixel area

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class NotTicTacToe extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new NotTicTacToe();
    }
    public NotTicTacToe() {
        setTitle("Not Tic Tac Toe");
        setSize(450, 800);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setResizable(false);
        setVisible(true);
        JTextField textfield1= new JTextField ("PLAY",50);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.drawRect(200, 257, 50, 50);
        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g.fillRect(201, 258, 49, 49);
        g.drawString("Play",50, 50);
    }

}
```

Comment: I do not see any such issue. I can not find where you have set a white background in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Add `super.paint(g);` to the start of your paint method. This calls the paint method in the JFrame class that your NotTicTacToe class inherits from.

Comment: Thank you for the help, it fixed the problem. Though I am not understanding what exactly this line of code did. If you don't mind could you explain the function of it? Thank you.

Comment: Your class inherits from the JFrame class. This means it has access to all the methods in the JFrame class. The paint method you have written is overriding the paint method in the JFrame class. 'super.paint(g)' calls the paint method in the JFrame class. Google how inheritance works in Java for a better explanation.